# Magnific PopUp error - opens on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I am a newbie to java script code, though have a fairly good understand of css and html coding. I was excited and doing a test of the magnific popup for mywebsite but I can't seem to make it work. I read through the documentation, but I'm clearly still missing something, as it opens on it's own page rather than staying on the same url. I have put it on a javascript test site, and it keeps telling it me that there is a problem with the code "$(document).ready(function() {"

Here is the code as I have it:

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css"> 
<style>

   .image-link {
   cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
   cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
   cursor: zoom-in;
}

/* aligns caption to center */
.mfp-title {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 6px 0;
 }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },
    image: {
        tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
        titleSrc: function(item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
        }
    }
});
});
//]]>
</script>

<div class="popup-gallery">
<a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" title="The Cleaner">      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>

</div>
<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
 <script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Seems you've misplaced the class attribute

Instead of assigning it to the `div` tag:

```
<div class="popup-gallery">
```

Add it to the  `a` tag:

```
<div>
  <a class="popup-gallery" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" title="The Cleaner">  
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
  </a> 
</div>
```